# Ensure that c# Assemby are deterministic

Tags: c#, deterministic, non-deterministic

It is possible to restrict specific classes, such as *Random* or *DateTime*, or the use of *float* in an AppDomain. Is it possible to detect it by reflection if you use them? or should we look at the IL code?

I would like to make a plugin system, but I have to make sure that the executed code is deterministic. Any other ideas on how to deal with it?

Thanks.

Comment: So, if I write ``int localInt = 0;`` somewhere in my code, and you "restricted" the usage of int you would like to say `Sorry, but no ints permitted` ?

Comment: The number of restrictions you'd need to put in place to ensure determinism is so high that I think that starting from C# and taking things away would be the wrong approach. Just the number of things inside mscorlib and System.Core that could be leveraged to achieve non-determinism is huge.

Comment: Following @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it might be possible to find or develop a deterministic scripting language. However, a plugin system that doesn't allow file access (non-deterministic contents), user interaction (non-deterministic input) and a lot more doesn't sound very interesting to me.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what's the idea behind doing thus?

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Type white list is possible to do that job

```
 readonly static List<string> WhiteList = new List<string>()
    {
        #region Basics
        typeof(Boolean).FullName,
        typeof(Char).FullName,
        typeof(String).FullName,
        typeof(Byte).FullName,
        typeof(SByte).FullName,
        typeof(UInt16).FullName,
        typeof(Int16).FullName,
        typeof(UInt32).FullName,
        typeof(Int32).FullName,
        typeof(UInt64).FullName,
        typeof(Int64).FullName,
        typeof(Decimal).FullName,
        typeof(Double).FullName,
        typeof(Single).FullName,
        typeof(TimeSpan).FullName,

        typeof(Array).FullName,
        typeof(Enum).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Exceptions
        typeof(Exception).FullName,
        typeof(NotImplementedException).FullName,
        typeof(IOException).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Delegates
        typeof(Delegate).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Parallel
        typeof(Parallel).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Conversions
        typeof(Convert).FullName,
        typeof(BitConverter).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Streams
        typeof(Stream).FullName,
        typeof(MemoryStream).FullName,
        typeof(BinaryReader).FullName,
        typeof(BinaryWriter).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Interfaces
        typeof(IDisposable).FullName,
        typeof(IComparable).FullName,
        typeof(IConvertible).FullName,
        typeof(IFormatProvider).FullName,
        typeof(IFormattable).FullName,
        typeof(IOrderedQueryable).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Attributes
        typeof(Attribute).FullName,

        // Compilation JIT
        typeof(CompilationRelaxationsAttribute).FullName,
        typeof(RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute).FullName,
        typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).FullName,
        #endregion

        #region Generic Types
        typeof(IDictionary<object,object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IDictionary<object,object>).Name,
        typeof(Dictionary<object,object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(Dictionary<object,object>).Name,
        typeof(List<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(List<object>).Name,
        typeof(IList<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IList<object>).Name,
        typeof(IEnumerable<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IEnumerable<object>).Name,
        typeof(IEnumerator<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IEnumerator<object>).Name,
        typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<object>).Name,
        typeof(IOrderedQueryable<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IOrderedQueryable<object>).Name,
        typeof(ICollection<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(ICollection<object>).Name,
        typeof(IComparable<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IComparable<object>).Name,
        typeof(IEquatable<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IEquatable<object>).Name,
        typeof(IObservable<object>).Namespace+"."+typeof(IObservable<object>).Name,
        #endregion
    };

    const string WhiteListedNamespace = "XX.XXXXXXXXXX.";

    /// <summary>
    /// Check white list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="binary">Binary</param>
    public static void CheckWhiteList(byte[] binary)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binary))
        {
            AssemblyDefinition def = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(ms, new ReaderParameters(ReadingMode.Immediate));

            List<string> ls = new List<string>();
            foreach (ModuleDefinition mdef in def.Modules)
                foreach (TypeReference tdef in mdef.GetTypeReferences())
                {
                    if (!WhiteList.Contains(tdef.FullName) &&
                        !tdef.FullName.StartsWith(WhiteListedNamespace, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                        ls.Add(tdef.FullName);
                }

            if (ls.Count > 0)
                throw (new TypeNotAllowedException(ls.ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the IL with something like [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil)[*]. But then again, it is possible to get access to those things via reflection.

[*]: Which would take some time, prompting you to cache the results..., which would introduce a vulnerability in which the attacker mimic a valid entry in the cache.

On the other hand, you could use a [sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox) [without Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304016/how-to-deny-reflection-using-reflectionpermission). You will have to combine that with the above approach.

Then, there are ways to mimic the behavior of what you describe... for example, you can create your own [Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) (which is something totally deterministic, by the way) and seed it with the current time or other source of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)) (you probably want to deny access to the file system and the network, and even to peripherals and other system status - for example an script could yield a different result depending on the pointer position).

Thus, I would suggest to have a [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) instead of [blacklist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist_(computing)) as [Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387182/ensure-that-c-sharp-assemby-are-deterministic#comment81727471_47387182).